# I am not able to update sticker pack which is already added to whatsApp in android

Tags: android, kotlin, whatsapp-stickers

I configure content provider so that my application can communicate to whatsapp. I am able to add packs to whatsApp but when I added new sticker to my existing pack; it is added to application pack but in whatsApp pack that sticker is not updated although when I open sticker pack my application content's provider overriden function get whatsApp query and there sticker list updated but whatsapp not able to update my pack. It will be great help if anyone guide me as I am new to android development. Thankyou in advance...

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: any Update on this?